# Create a LogDNA appender for log4js in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, appender, log4js-node, logdna

I want to create a `LogDNA` appender for my `log4js` logger, so below is my code. The issue I have is with the `configure` function. Actually I don't know what is the type of `layouts`, I know it's a function but couldn't find its type in `log4js` typescript :

```
import { logDnaLogger } from './logging'
import * as log4js from 'log4js'

// This is the function that generates an appender function
function appender(layout: Function, timezoneOffset: string): Function {
    const appender = (loggingEvent: log4js.LoggingEvent): void => {
        logDnaLogger.info(`${layout(loggingEvent, timezoneOffset)}\n`)
    }

    appender.shutdown = (done: Function): void => {
        logDnaLogger.info('LOGDNA ------ SHUTDOWN')
        done()
    }

    return appender
}

function configure(config: log4js.Configuration, layouts: ??????????): Function {
    let layout = layouts.colouredLayout
    if (config.layout) {
        layout = layouts.layout(config.layout.type, config.layout)
    }
    //create a new appender instance
    return appender(layout, config.timezoneOffset)
}

export const logdnaAppender = { configure }
```

Comment: the type `Layout` is exported from `log4js.d.ts`. Please clarify

Comment: @AluanHaddad the function `configure` takes 2 arguments: config and layouts. `layouts` is not of type `Layout`.

Comment: Well, if you don't know what `layouts` is, you could start by describing its known capabilities based on your own usage: `function configure(log4js.Configuration, layouts: {coloredLayout: log4js.ColoredLayout, layout: (t: string, l: Layout)=> void}) { ... }`.